# The APNS PushNotifcation Service is thorwing "Remote host closed connection during handshake"

Tags: java, google-kubernetes-engine, istio, javapns

I have created a micro Service application and added the APNS library of type "com.notnoop.apns" and version "1.0.0.Beta6".I have deployed this application on GCP on a kubernetes Cluster. The push Notifications were working fine. But sometimes I am getting the below Exception

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:994)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1367)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:750)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:123)
    at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:75)
    at com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsConnectionImpl.sendMessage(ApnsConnectionImpl.java:328)
    at com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsConnectionImpl.sendMessage(ApnsConnectionImpl.java:312)
    at com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsServiceImpl.push(ApnsServiceImpl.java:46)
    at com.notnoop.apns.internal.AbstractApnsService.push(AbstractApnsService.java:89)
    at com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsServiceImpl.push(ApnsServiceImpl.java:36)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:580)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:505)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:975)
    ... 22 common frames omitted
```

This issue is being Reproduced many times now a days and If I am Restarting the Service in google Cloud, Then the Push Notifications are Working Fine but again after sometime I am facing the same issue. I have even checked with the validity of the Certificate and its not Expired yet.

Comment: Are you using a Private Cluster and NAT Gateway?

Comment: Yes we are using a private cluster..

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, please reserve some time to read [**how to create a minimal, reproducible example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and provide us more info from your structure, like the yaml files, versions and steps to reproduce the issue, this way you enable the community to help you and you allow others with similar issues to be helped as well.